# Exact Date Syntax - Custom SQL Query

Tags: sql, tableau-desktop, tableau-prep

I am working on a custom SQL query in Tableau Prep using an Oracle data source. I usually write my SQL in another platoform, and am having trouble finding the right exact date syntax.

What is the correct syntax for the example below?

```
and (invc_date > {ts'2022-12-31 00:00:00'}    
or drft_date > {ts'2022-12-31 00:00:00'} 
or drft_date is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use TO_DATE function to convert a string to a date value

```
TO_DATE('2022-12-31 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```